# LinqToTwitter generate exception when i try to send privatemessage

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, linq-to-twitter

i try to send private message to followers of a user who is already authenticated with my_app, here is the code :

```
    var authent = new MvcAuthorizer
        {
            Credentials = new SessionStateCredentials()
            {
                ConsumerKey = this.client.ConsumerKey,
                ConsumerSecret = this.client.ConsumerSecret,
                OAuthToken = identity.Token.Token
            }
        };

        var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(authent);
        list_friend.ToList().ForEach(x => twitterCtx.NewDirectMessage(x.InvitedFriendID, messageWithPlaceHolders.Replace("[FRIEND_NAME]", x.Name)));
```

list_friend is the list of followers of the user who is authenticated.

Pleaaaase i need your help.

Comment: Which kind of exception on which line? Can you post the exception message and the stacktrace?

Comment: here is the exception : Le serveur distant a retourné une erreur : (401) Non autorisé.

Comment: and this too : "Error while querying Twitter.". the exception is generate by the last instruction : "list_friend.TOList()......."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is to use the InMemoryCrendentials rather than SessionStateCredentials and add the token secret to crendential, and after we should add DateTime.Now to the message because twitter don't allow duplicate message, here is the code off the solution it work well :

```
  var authent = new MvcAuthorizer
        {
            Credentials = new InMemoryCredentials()
            {
                ConsumerKey = this.client.ConsumerKey,
                ConsumerSecret = this.client.ConsumerSecret,
                OAuthToken = identity.Token.Token,
                AccessToken = identity.Token.Secret
            }
        };
  var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(authent);            
  list_friend.ToList().ForEach(x => twitterCtx.NewDirectMessage(x.SocialId, messageWithPlaceHolders.Replace("[FRIEND_NAME]", x.Name) +DateTime.Now.ToString()));
```

Thanks